# Google App Engine indexed property with None value

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

To my surprise, an indexed property with a None value in GAE still counts towards write costs, and is still indexed. Apparently, this can be desired behavior in some circumstances, according to this post:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-appengine/pRHA85s3U-o/frdJeab8RVwJ

Also according to that post is something called "partial indexes", but that's for Java. I'm using NDB with Python. I'd like for indexed properties with None values not to be indexed, and not count towards write costs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible unless you use an Expando. You could also hack it using a repeated property (0 or 1 items) but that changes the way your app sees it.

Comment: I like Expando, but it's very limited in that it's all or nothing - either every property is indexed or no property is indexed. Is it not possible to pick and choose which property is indexed with Expando? I never understood why that isn't possible..

Comment: Read the ndb source code. You should be able to manually create an ad hoc GenericProperty with indexed=<bool>.